# Including value from another class in thymeleaf view page

Tags: html, spring, thymeleaf

I am new to thymeleaf and have to convert all my jsp files to thymeleaf.Well i have a external class file as given below:

### Info.java

```
public class Info{
 public String filePath="http://localhost:8080/myapp/cssfolder";
}
```

and now that i would like to include it in my thymeleaf css file such that

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
  <link href="${filePath}/StyleSheet.css"   type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
</head>
<body> ... </body>
</html>
```

i have also sent the value as a model map in my controller.Still i dont get the value of filepath in the link.It only displays link as "{$filePath}/StyleSheet.css" while running the page.Please somebody help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do:

```
<link th:href="${filePath}/stylesheet.css" href="static_url"   type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Where `static_url` is the path in your HTML mockups.